# Need a custom assignment implementaion

Tags: javascript, immutability

I am working with some state management application where I have a data structure as follows

```
const mainObject = {
    firstLevel: {
        secondLevel: {
            thirdLevel: {
                actualProperty: 'Secret'
            }
        }
    },
    firstLevelUntouched:{
        secondLevelUntouched:{
            thirdLevelUntouched:{
                untouchedProperty:'I don`t want to change'
            }
        }
    }
};
```

I want to change the actualProperty to a new value which out a deepClone

I did it with the following code

```
const modified = {
    ...mainObject,
    ...{
        firstLevel: {
            ...mainObject.firstLevel,
            ...{
                secondLevel: {
                    ...mainObject.firstLevel.secondLevel,
                    thirdLevel: {
                        ...mainObject.firstLevel.secondLevel.thirdLevel,
                        actualProperty: 'New secret'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But its looks like Bulky Code. So I need to write a function like

modified = myCustomAssignment(mainObject, ['firstLevel', 'secondLevel', 'thirdLevel', 'actualProperty'], 'New secret')

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Have you tried `let modified = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(mainObject))` to get a new copy of the  `mainObject` object. If that is good for you, then you can do `modified.firstLevel.secondLevel.thirdLevel.actualProperty = "New secret";`. Note the combination of `JSON.stringify()` and `JSON.parse()` will not work if your object includes complex structures, like `Maps`, `Sets`, `Functions`, etc...

Comment: You have almost described how https://github.com/immutable-js/immutable-js works. But it is not always which worth adds it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
export function mutateState(mainObject: object, propertyList: string[], newValue: any) {
    const lastProp = propertyList.pop();
    const newState: object = { ...mainObject };
    const propertyTree =
        propertyList
            .reduce((obj, prop) => {
                obj[prop] = { ...newState[prop], ...obj[prop] };
                return obj[prop];
            }, newState);
    propertyTree[lastProp] = newValue;
    return newState as unknown;
}
```

This fixed my issue. thanks all..

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple traversal function for this that just traverses the passed properties until it arrives as the final one, then sets that to the new value.

```
function myCustomAssignment(mainObject, propertyList, newValue) {
   const lastProp = propertyList.pop();
   const propertyTree = propertyList.reduce((obj, prop) => obj[prop], mainObject);
   propertyTree[lastProp] = newValue;
}
```

You could even add `propertyList = propertyList.split('.')` to the top of this function so the list can be passed in as an easy-to-read string, like `myCustomAssignment(mainObject, 'firstLevel.secondLevel.thirdLevel.actualProperty', 'new value')` if you wanted that.